# How to convert "PT5H" to ticks using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to convert "PT5H" to ticks format using powershell. But facing below error:

```
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SuppressionDuration'. Cannot convert value "PT5H" to type "System.TimeSpan". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan."
```

Can anyone help me out in converting "PT5H"(String) to ticks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.totimespan?view=netframework-4.8) to parse ISO8601 duration strings:

```
$duration = [System.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan('PT5H')
Command-Name -SuppressionDuration $duration
```